# SSMS unable to generate script the Databasae with Trigger

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a database with more than 50 tables and lots of triggers. Right now, I am unable to generate the scripts using the Sql Server Management Studio with enabling the Triggers.

Whenever I tried to generate scripts with Triggers, it gives a Out of Memory exception. Don't know how come this kind of errors persist in Microsoft Products but its really annoying me and my client.

Here's the error message which I got:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.GeneratePublishPage.worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

Comment: are you using any hard coded value ?

Comment: Hardcoded values like what?

Comment: This type of error comes when your Datatype is unable to hold the value you are specifying, as you are getting error in compilation, hence it must be hard coded in the code you are compiling

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Recovery model by going to
YourDB -> properties ->options tab and change the Recovery model to simple

[image]